# IE expected ')' error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am receiving the following error in IE which is stopping the page from loading. I have tried to find this error but for the life of me cannot see it. The portion of the code that the error points to is here at jsfiddle.net:

http://jsfiddle.net/SrgsC/

I would be grateful if someone could point out the offending error? Many thanks

I am using php5.3.5

```
Message: Expected ')'
Line: 2867
Char: 41
Code: 0
URI: http://sample.com/admin/cp.php


Message: Expected ')'
Line: 2867
Char: 40
Code: 0
URI: http://sample.com/admin/cp.php
```

Comment: those are Javacsript errors, not PHP errors.

Comment: You should avoid to mix HTML/PHP like that

Comment: Also, JSFiddle doesn't work with PHP code, so your JSFiddle isn't much use.

Comment: what line is 2867 in the fiddle? + the error probably comes from the generated file

Comment: The code you posted does not contain any mistakes, but like Spudley already mentioned it's a javascript error message you have.

Comment: @bolio the problem is not coming from php, because browsers don't interpret PHP, it's done on you're server.

Comment: show the line affected in your js

Comment: @yes123 yeh i inherited it to try and sort out. should put it up for an award :-)

Comment: what would be the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @bollo: Debug only the HTML/JS output from PHP. Narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: btw there is no javascript in that page apart from what I posted in the code

Comment: @tomalak well firebug is showing no errors, so what other way will help me sort this? thanks

Comment: @bollo: Can you direct us to a the page or at least a fully generated page? I would be happy to take a look, but right now there is not much I can do.

Comment: @lbu the code I posted is the affected line

Comment: @bollo: Firebug might not show any error(s) for certain 'mistakes' Firefox automatically fixes (like an additional `,` at the end of an object), but Internet Explorer will still fail to execute it.

Comment: @bollo: You're jumping ahead again. Narrow the scope of the problem. Do not write anything more here until you have removed PHP from this question; post a new Fiddle to prove that you have narrowed the problem to HTML & Javascript.

Comment: @kilzone unfortunately there is to much client data to post

Comment: @tomalak please see my earlier comment about debugging code?

Comment: @bollo: Yes, I was responding to it. Narrow. Down. The. Problem.

Comment: @bollo: I might be wrong, but generally your Javascript should be 'client data'-free and thus you should be able to make a JSFiddle with just that (javascript) code. Also know that anything you include in a `script`-tag might be your problem (jQuery, jQuery plugins, own code, etc.), you should narrow that down first.

Comment: @tomalak that comment was as useful as a chocolate teapot...

Comment: @bollo: I happen to know a lot more than you do about how to debug an application, which is why you've asked our opinion here today. If you wish to ignore the answer, than that's your choice. I give up!

Comment: @kilzone the only piece of JS is that i snippet I posted. I now need to start digging. Thanks eveyone for your help

Comment: @bollo, I think you need to start believing your commenters. What you posted *is not* javascript. That is server code. That is not what IE is complaining about. Really.

Comment: Mmm...chocolate teapot...om nom nom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the code you provided is in PHP, not JavaScript. If this is only happening in IE, then it is clear that you have put a PHP function in a JavaScript file. Otherwise, it should be happening in IE, FF, Chrome...

Some issues with the PHP function at any rate:

- you start with `$print .=` . This means, "add the following string to the $print" variable, but $print is not defined in that function. If it is a global variable, you need to put `global $print;` on the line before it, or, if it is local, then you need to use `$print =` (no '.')
- `mysql_numrows` should be `mysql_num_rows` unless you've created your own numrows function
- `mysql_result` should not be used that way. To quote the docs:

> When working on large result sets, you should consider using one of the functions that fetch an entire row
>
> You should not be manually iterating through rows by tracking the current row number (the same reason as above)
>
> A 15 parameter function is too many. It is way to many. The maximum which can be handled effectively are 7 (according to Code Complete), the more zealous would argue for even fewer (Uncle Bob, I believe, says 3 is a good standard). Either way, if I saw 8 or more parameters in a method during a code review I would immediately know something needed to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for that concise and clear answer. I now have a starting point.

Comment: "If this is only happening in IE"... just for the record, it is quite common for errors to happen in IE that do not happen in other browsers, because IE (esp. <9) is less forgiving about some things such as missing semicolons. It also has some things that are implemented differently like `setTimeout`. Actually javascript errors that happen in IE but not anywhere else are the bane of my existence.

Comment: I know. That's why I made the commend about the other browsers.